# Firing an event once a td contenteditable cell changes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which I need to let the user modify a numeric field only and it looks like the neatest way to do it is modifying the cell itself. On the server side I have a method that responds with a success:true if the change in the database is successful or success:false for the opposite.

```
<td class="editQty" contenteditable>1000</td>
```

So I want that every time the user modifies this td cell a callback is made. Will 'change' jQuery function be aware of this modification. I've read that it doesn't.

I tried input already and that is noticed but it also changes before the user stops editing. I was wondering if there is a sort of event that can be fired when the user loses focus of the td.

```
$('tr').on('input', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
        alert("whatever");
    });
```

Comment: <td class="editQty" contenteditable>1000</td> or <td class="editQty contenteditable" >1000</td> question was clear, can you pls paster your   table

Comment: blur is the opposite of focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('tr').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
    alert("whatever");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a standard `input` element for taking the value entered by the user and apply the `.blur()` (and maybe also a `.keypress()`) event on it, along with some dom manipulation it could go like this:

```js
$('td[contenteditable]').on('click', function() {
  var td = $(this);
  if(!td.hasClass('editing')){
  td.addClass('editing');
  
  var input = $('<input value="'+td.text()+'"/>');
  
  input.on('blur', function(){
    //fire ajax
    console.log('fire ajax');
    /*next line goes inside ajax:success*/
    td.text(input.val());
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('input removed');
    td.removeClass('editing');
  });
  
  $(this).empty().append(input);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>header</th></tr>
<tr><td class="editQty" contenteditable>1000</td></tr>

</table>
```